# Tamarin-prover Issue on a Basic Diffie-Hellman Exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman, protocol-analysis

I am starting [Tamarin prover](https://tamarin-prover.github.io/), and it is hard to understand.

Here is a basic example of my issue:

**First Code :**

```
theory test 
begin

builtins : asymmetric-crypto, diffie-hellman

rule Register_pk:
    [Fr(~ltkA)]-->[!Ltk($A, ~ltkA), !Pk($A, pk(~ltkA)), Out(pk(~ltkA))]

rule C1:
    [Fr(~x)]
    -->[C1($C, ~x), Out(<$C, 'g'^~x)>]

rule S1:
    let pubkeyC = 'g'^x in
    [Fr(~y), In(<C, pubkeyC)>]
    --[ Secret($S, C, pubkeyC^~y)]->
    [S1($S, ~y, pubkeyC)]

lemma Secret_dh:
"
    All S C dh_secret #i. Secret(S, C, dh_secret)@#i ==> not( Ex #k. K(dh_secret)@#k)
"
end
```

after a : *tamarin-prover --prove test.spthy* the lemma is verified

Then I only change the lemma into :

**Second Code :**

```
lemma Secret_dh:
exists-trace
"
    All S C dh_secret #i. Secret(S, C, dh_secret)@#i ==> Ex #k. K(dh_secret)@#k
"
```

And after a : *tamarin-prover --prove test.spthy* the lemma is verified too.

I find this completely abnormal.

Comment: Please note the [crypto tools discussion](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1120/1172) on our meta. Also, there seems to be just one Tamarin related question on [SO], so migration there won't help Hlen much.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try asking this on the [Tamarin google group](https://groups.google.com/g/tamarin-prover)? I'm guessing that's the right place to ask such a question and get a good answer.

Though from a first glance, I would guess that the empty trace (or any trace in which no Secret fact occurs) satisfies your second lemma, and this is thus entirely expected behavior.

Intuitively, your second lemma states: there exists a trace, such that (if a Secret fact occurs in it, then the adversary knows the secret). This trivially holds for any trace without a Secret fact, and thus the lemma indeed holds.

Or, put differently, your second lemma is not the negation of the first lemma.

Answer (score 0):

user4621 already answered the question.

Some additional notes:

- The code has syntax errors. You can catch these by using the `--quit-on-warning` flag.
- The exists-trace is useful for making sure the protocol can be executed:

  > To ensure that our lemmas do not just hold vacuously because the model is not executable, we also include an executability lemma that shows that the model can run to completion. This is given as a regular lemma, but with the exists-trace keyword (...)
  >
  > https://tamarin-prover.github.io/manual/book/003_example.html
- The `Register_pk` is never used, I'm assuming it is for later.

---

I fixed the warnings and commented out the unused rule:

```
theory test 
begin

builtins : /*asymmetric-encryption,*/ diffie-hellman

/*
rule Register_pk:
    [Fr(~ltkA)]-->[!Ltk($A, ~ltkA), !Pk($A, pk(~ltkA)), Out(pk(~ltkA))]
*/

rule C1:
    [Fr(~x)]
    -->[C1($C, ~x), Out(<$C, 'g'^~x>)]

rule S1:
    let pubkeyC = 'g'^x in
    [Fr(~y), In(<C, pubkeyC>)]
    --[ Secret($S, C, pubkeyC^~y)]->
[S1($S, ~y, pubkeyC)]

lemma Secret_dh:
"
    All S C dh_secret #i. Secret(S, C, dh_secret)@#i ==> not( Ex #k. K(dh_secret)@#k)
"

end
```

Execution:

````
$ tamarin-prover --quit-on-warning test.spthy --prove
...
==============================================================================
summary of summaries:

analyzed: test.spthy

  processing time: 0.030276719s
  
  Secret_dh (all-traces): verified (20 steps)

==============================================================================
```
````